# How can I use awk to print a numeric index based on a matching pattern?

Tags: awk

I have a comma-separated file with two columns like so:

```
A,france
B,france
C,germany
D,germany
E,germany
F,spain
G,spain
```

I want to use awk (or any similar tool) to print a numeric value for each of the different groups (countries in this example). i.e.

```
A,france,1
B,france,1
C,germany,2
D,germany,2
E,germany,2
F,spain,3
G,spain,3
```

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this without having to specify every single group manually?

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then(not my downvote btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an associative array `t` for the team numbers. For each line, test if the team is not yet a key in the array (value will equate to empty string), and in that case, increment the value of counter `i` and set the value in the `t` array to the counter value after this increment.  Then print the whole line (`$0`), followed by the value looked up from the associative array.

The `-F, -v OFS=,` uses field separator `,` on both input and output.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{if (t[$2]=="") {t[$2]=++i}; print $0,t[$2]}' filename
```

gives

```
A,france,1
B,france,1
C,germany,2
D,germany,2
E,germany,2
F,spain,3
G,spain,3
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful and a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner works no matter the countries are sorted or not in the input file:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]:++i}$3=a[$2]' file
```

For example:

```
$  awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{a[$2]=a[$2]?a[$2]:++i}$3=a[$2]' f 
A,france,1
B,france,1
C,germany,2
D,germany,2
E,germany,2
F,spain,3
G,spain,3
H,germany,2
I,germany,2
J,spain,3
```